# Can we find rank of each element in array with Linear Time Complexity O(n)?

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, hashmap, ranking

I am trying to solve [this Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-transform-of-an-array/), where it is asked to solve:

> Given an array of integers arr, replace each element with its rank.
> For example:
>
> Input: arr = [40,10,20,30]
> Output: [4,1,2,3]
> Explanation: 40 is the largest element. 10 is the smallest. 20 is the second smallest. 30 is the third smallest.

My code is as follows:

```
    class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> arrayRankTransform(vector<int>& arr) {
        multimap<int, int> numbeToIndexrMap;
        int size = arr.size();
        vector<int> rank(size, 10);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            numbeToIndexrMap.insert({arr[i], i});
        }
        int rankIndex = 1;
        int previous = INT_MIN;
        for(auto i = numbeToIndexrMap.begin(); i != numbeToIndexrMap.end(); ){
            int currentNumber = i -> first;
            rank[i->second] = rankIndex;
            ++i;
            if(i != numbeToIndexrMap.end() && i -> first != currentNumber) ++rankIndex;
        }
        return rank;
    }
};
```

I found that we may use Sorting/Map to solve this problem with time complexity of O(NlogN). My question is whether we can do this on linear time O(n)?

Comment: I do not think this problem can be solved without sorting the array, which definitely costs `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: Pasting external links to problems without trying anything of your own is highly discouraged.

Comment: @Akash Dahane Actually I tried and then only I'm asking for any suggestions :)

Comment: @biqarboy I agree on your point. I tried in all possible ways and searched a lot about this. What ever the algo is, it's cose is O(NlogN) only. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in the hint section of that problem, they expect us to sort the array which will itself take time complexity of `O(nlog(n))`. Here, sorting is not important but necessary part of solution. So the thing that makes difference is how you search the rank from that sorted array.
Naive approach will be to find `index` of `each` element of the original array in the sorted array using `linear search` `O(n)`. So overall time complexity would be `O(n*n)`.
Best approach would be to find index of each element of original array in the sorted array using `binary search` `O(log(n))`. So the overall time complexity would be `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: I think O(n*log(n)) is the lowest possible time complexity that we can achieve for this problem.

Comment: Yes. That's only possible solution. If your solution is not being accepted, then either your implementation is incorrect or your solution exceeds O(nlog(n)). You should re-evaluate your solution.

Comment: @AkashDahane You do not need to make binary search each time, instead you can simply use `Sorting and Map` to solve this problem. Unordered Map even offer `O(1)` average insert/lookup time.